# Create dictionary out of txt file. One alphabet letter per row. Key is letter and value should be iteration of the loop

Tags: python, dictionary

i got a problem..
I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
a
b
c
d
```

One letter per row, there is not two values per row, so nothing to split..

```
This code works, if I add a second value in my alphabetFile.
dict = {}
with open("alphabet.txt") as alphabetFile:
    for line in alphabetFile:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        dict[int(key)] = val

print(dict)
```

But I should only have 1 value per row... Im thinking the iteration should be the second value.. but im stuck and tired.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate over lines. Also, don't use `dict` as name of variable (it shadows Python built-in):

```py
dct = {}
with open("alphabet.txt") as alphabetFile:
    for iteration, line in enumerate(alphabetFile, 1):
        dct[line.strip()] = iteration

print(dct)
```

Prints:

```py
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: Yes!! thank you! that works perfectly! damn I used enumerate not long ago! :S